# Can i get the publication dates for previous versions in SDL TRIDION 2011?

Tags: tridion

In an application,there is a requirement of getting Published dates of all the previous versions.Is there any way of doing this in Tridion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tridion does not maintain a complete record of all publish dates of an item. Through the API you can find out which targets an item is currently published to, and when the last publishing action occurred.

As a work-around you could use the event system to track one of the publish events, and store the URI (including version) of the published items in a separate database.

Comment: Often the stakeholder who specifies this kind of requirement isn't familiar with the Tridion publishing model. Simply knowing the published date isn't much use if you don't know what actually got published at that time, so you'd want the versions of all relevant components, etc. It's often worth going in to a discussion to help everyone understand what is wanted, and what is reasonable to implement.